# Common formal / informal verbs used for changing clothes

Tags: verb-usage

Regarding the following sentences, I think both mean exactly the same and the only point that hey differ is their formality level, where the sentences #1 sounds more casual and usable only in informal speech, whereas the latter one can be used both is informal and more formal speech:

> - **1.** When I get home from work, I get changed.
> - **2.** When I get home from work, I change.

Comment: how do you change? do you turn into a werewolf?

Comment: You could use both in everyday conversation - but be prepared for the werewolf-type joke because of the ambiguity in the second instance. In fact, joke aside, the second one feels like you're going to add something like, "I'm no longer tense, I can relax"

Comment: If the context makes it clear that you are discussing clothing, then the second one would be fine.  _"I hate my uniform!  The shirt is too tight, and the boots are too hot.  When I get home from work, I change."_  Otherwise, the first sentence would be preferable, for the reasons given by @Tetsujin and cVplZ

Answer (score 2):

In the title, you specify that you are talking about changing the clothes and thus,

> When I get home from work, I change

serves the purpose. On the other hand, *got/get changed*, as said in the comment talks about transformation.

Also, note that if you say, *I get change*, it **may also mean** that you got change of USD 100! We often use the phrase, *"Can you get me (some) change?"*

In short, to avoid ambiguity, prefer the sentence number one. :)

Comment: Maulik, thank you very much for your nice and informative comments my friend. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In this situation you are supposed to use the phrasal verb **'Change out of'**

See these examples

1. I don’t feel good unless I change out of my office clothes as soon as I get home from work.
2. He had come home from his school half an hour ago, but he went out to play without changing out of his school uniform. (He is playing with his school uniform on)
3. Why haven't you changed out of your office clothes yet ? (Why are you still wearing your office clothes?)

Here **'change into'** is also used

Suppose you went over to your friends place and you are going to a party. But when you see the shirt your friend wearing is not appropriate for the occassion, then you tell him

1. Hey, what don't you go and change into a nicer shirt ? We are going to a party. (which means go and put on a nicer shirt and come back)

More examples

1. Would you mind waiting here till i just change into my sports shoes in a minute ? (Means i'll go and put on my sports shoes and will come back)
2. You will have to change into a swim suit if you want to take a swim in this pool. Those regular clothes are not allowed.